# Smoke filled up my cabin

Tags: hyundai

I have hyundai elantra 2017. I started my car and after few minutes heard sound of air leaking and was suddenly filled up with smoke inside the car. What could the problem be? Should i drive my car or tow it to repairs?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Call Hyundai and have them tow it! Your car should be covered under their 5yr/60k warranty, which I believe covers towing as well. Not safe for you to be inside the passenger compartment with it filling full of smoke, for whatever reason.

Comment: Could be anything, post some more info?

Comment: A likely source may be the air conditioning - did the smoke dissipate relatively quickly? You would recognise a burning smell... But let it air out before you get in it again and, really, best to get it towed.

Comment: If it really was smoke, I don't think you would even be asking the question "can I drive it". You wouldn't be able to breathe properly! On the other hand if it was *water vapour* ("steam") from something like a leaky heater radiator, apart from fogging up the windows you wouldn't come to much harm driving it. A very small amount of water goes a long way, when it gets vaporized.

Comment: … I used to have an old Ford which leaked about a teaspoon of water a day from the heater radiator into some foam rubber padding that surrounded it. When the car warmed up the "steam" from that filled the interior for about 30 seconds before it dispersed. I knew it was going to happen and opened the windows to let it out. The only problem was sitting at a red light one day with steam billowing from the driver's window, when some "helpful" person in another car jumped out and tried to empty the contents of a fire extinguisher all over me, before I could wind the window up and stop him!

Comment: It was smoke. I had just started my car and started the heat and was waiting for my friend when all of a sudden the sound of something leaking cane and filled up the cabin with smoke. I just turned off my car and waited for smoke to go. The smell was something I cant tell as it wasn't  that of burning but was quite strong

Comment: Sounds like the refrigerant leaked out of the AC system into the passenger compartment.